# Android OpenCV - "error: cannot find -lopencv_java"

Tags: android, opencv, intellij-idea, android-ndk

I'm trying to develope a native code with OpenCV using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4. When I try to ndk-build the code provided in mixedprocessing sample, I have this error:

```
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: com_sample_jniLib <= com_sample_jniLib.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libcom_sample_jniLib.so
D:/Workspace/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: cannot find -lopencv_java
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libcom_voxar_tracker_TrackerLib.so] Error 1
D:\Workspace\android-ndk-r10\sources\cxx-stl\stlport\stlport
```

Basically, he can't find -lopencv_java.

Here is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include jni/opencv/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_voxar_tracker_TrackerLib.cpp
LOCAL_MODULE := com_voxar_tracker_TrackerLib
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And my Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := all
```

As I told before, I'm using **IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4**, **OpenCV 2.4.9** and **Android NDK r10 32-bit** on **Windows 8.1**. Does anybody have any idea of what that could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have forgot `OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on` in your **Android.mk**:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include jni/opencv/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_voxar_tracker_TrackerLib.cpp
LOCAL_MODULE := com_voxar_tracker_TrackerLib
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexCohn, that solved my problem. In fact, when I did what you suggested, another error came up. It was not finding the OpenCV libs. I tried to put their path on the Android.mk, but I had no success whatsoever. So I solved this the ugliest way: copying the libs folder to the path it was looking for. I will take a look at this after finishing my prototype.

Comment: Sometimes on Windows, it may be very tricky to define the paths in Android.mk